# Python for predefined Junit XML

Tags: python, junit

I have  to develop a python script that produces a Junit XML in following format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Scenario3" time="0.015">
        <testcase name="testcase09"/>
        <testcase name="testcase10">
            <skipped />
        </testcase>
        <testcase name="testcase11">
            <failure type="AssertionFailure">
            <![CDATA[ Failed 1 times. ]]>
            </failure>
       </testcase>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I did a basic python code but not able to mark  as shown above

```
from junit_xml import TestSuite, TestCase
test_cases = []
for result in results:
    tc_name, tc_result = result
    if tc_result == "PASS":
        test_cases.append(TestCase(tc_name))
        ts = TestSuite("S", test_cases)
print(TestSuite.to_xml_string([ts]))enter code here
```

Please do give your suggestion for the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Decode
       from junit_xml import TestSuite, TestCase, Decode

From the above we can mark test cases as fail/skipped etc